# Comparing superset object in golang

Tags: go

I want to compare two objects

```
expected:= `"{\"method\":\"GET\",\"body\":{},\"uploadCount\":0}"` 

result := `"{\"name\":\"xyz\",\"method\":\"GET\",\"body\":{},\"uploadCount\":0}"`
```

Now as we can see result is super-set of expected but when I use reflect.deepequal, it says false because it exactly compare two objects. I want to compare if result is superset of expected or not.

```
 func main(){

    result := "{\"name\":\"xyz\",\"method\":\"GET\",\"body\":{},\"uploadCount\":0}"

    expected := "{\"method\":\"GET\",\"body\":{},\"uploadCount\":0}" 

    var _result interface{}
    var _expected interface{}
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(result),&_result)
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(expected),&_expected)

    reflect.deepequal(_result,_expected)

}
```

Comment: You need to do some programming here. Write code which does what you want.

Comment: Can you please help.

Comment: SO is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 0):

Without any refinements you could do something like

```
func main() {

    result := "{\"name\":\"xyz\",\"method\":\"GET\",\"body\":{},\"uploadCount\":0}"

    expected := "{\"method\":\"GET\",\"body\":{},\"uploadCount\":0}"

    var _result map[string]interface{}
    var _expected map[string]interface{}

    json.Unmarshal([]byte(result), &_result)
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(expected), &_expected)

    isSuperset := true

    for k, v := range _expected {
        if !reflect.DeepEqual(v, _result[k]) {
            isSuperset = false
            break
        } 
    }

    fmt.Println(isSuperset)
}
```